# DataLoss: not an sstable(bad magic number) when restoring tensorflow graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection, yolo

LANGUAGE : python3.x

I trained an object recognition model using this API :https://github.com/thtrieu/darkflow

After training the checkpoints are stored in the `ckpt` folder. 4 files are saved.

1 .index file

2 .meta file

3 .profile file

4 .data-00000-of-00001 file

When I try to restore the graph on the machine I trained the model on it restores successfully and runs the model.

When I shift machines the graph fails to restore and throws the following error:

```
Running entirely on CPU
Loading from ./ckpt/yolov2-tiny-voc-1c-589
2018-12-30 20:43:14.628170: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1273] OP_REQUIRES failed at save_restore_v2_ops.cc:184 : Data loss: not an sstable (bad magic number)
2018-12-30 20:43:16.853852: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1273] OP_REQUIRES failed at save_restore_v2_ops.cc:184 : Data loss: not an sstable (bad magic number)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1334, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1319, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1407, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.DataLossError: not an sstable (bad magic number)
     [[{{node save/RestoreV2}} = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, ..., DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]
```

The complete error message is huge so I have posted it here :
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-FJezfP7COSIDvElAvHCR2wzln21c-_S

Please ask any for any more information you might need

Comment: What file name do you pass to restore?

Comment: the api accepts an 'options' argument so I gave this : options = {
    'model': 'cfg/yolov2-tiny-voc-1c.cfg',
    'load': 589,
    'threshold': 0.2,
 
}

Comment: Here the 'model' is the CFG to be loaded and 'load' refers to the `.data-00000-of-00001' file to be loaded. Notice that the key to load does not have quotation marks.

Comment: This works perfectly on the machine I trained the model on but not on any other machines I have tried

Comment: Are you sure the tensorflow versions are the same?

Comment: Yes both machines are running 1.12

Comment: Although one machine is using CPU and the other one GPU(the one I trained it on) but I tried running the same on colab (it is also running 1.12) and it did not work

Comment: @McAngus I can provide you with the complete darkflow folder that I am using if you need it. It inclues the trained model files.

Comment: @McAngus Even tried with tensorflow 1.0. Still showing same error